# Accessing authenticated user Azure Functions locally

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions, azure-authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I am building a SPA with Azure Functions in Typescript. I have authentication setup through my B2C. I have two app registrations - one for the SPA and another for the Azure Functions. I configured my scopes correctly, and I configured the authentication provider for my Azure Function in Azure.

Everything is working fine; however, I am currently trying to run the Azure Functions locally and access the authenticated user. I can see that `context.req.headers.authorization` is defined; however, `context.req.user` is undefined. Is there something I am missing to get to work running locally?

```
const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context): Promise<void> {
  const id = context.req.headers['X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID']; // undefined
  const user = context.req.user; // undefined
  ...
}
```

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "Anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/config/index.js"
}
```

[image]

I would expect for `context.req.user` to be defined or for there to be some other way to access the authenticated user information.

Comment: can you share your function code please?

Comment: The relevant function code is in the first code block.

Answer (score 0):

**X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID** header is set by App Service based on token. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-user-identities#access-user-claims-in-app-code